Unable to obtain chrome using Selenium Manager, --language-binding
I upgraded my Selenium from 4.6.0 to 4.19.0 and running a test gives me this error
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchDriverException : Unable to obtain chrome using Selenium Manager; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location
  ----> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Error starting process: C:\Automation\DevTools\ui-automation\UIAutomation\UIAutomation\bin\Debug\selenium-manager\windows\selenium-manager.exe  --browser "chrome" --language-binding csharp --output json
  ----> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Selenium Manager process exited abnormally with 2 code: C:\Automation\DevTools\ui-automation\UIAutomation\UIAutomation\bin\Debug\selenium-manager\windows\selenium-manager.exe  --browser "chrome" --language-binding csharp --output json

Error Output >>
error: Found argument '--language-binding' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context

  If you tried to supply '--language-binding' as a value rather than a flag, use '-- --language-binding'

Usage: selenium-manager.exe <--browser <BROWSER>|--driver <DRIVER>|--driver-version <DRIVER_VERSION>|--browser-version <BROWSER_VERSION>|--debug|--trace|--clear-cache>

For more information try '--help'

<<

TearDown : System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException : The given key was not present in the dictionary.


Selenium.WebDriver = 4.19.0
Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver = 126.0.6478.18200
Google Chrome = 126.0.6478.182

I have tried reinstalling Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver and deleting chromedriver.exe from bin/debug folder.

looks like the error is saying "--language-binding csharp --output json" are invalid flags.  Can you include your code?

Hi, did you find a solution for this? I just upgraded from 4.7.0 to 4.25.0 and I'm getting the exact same error in production on a Windows Server 2019 server. Works fine locally on Windows 11 though?!
